# Rails autocomplete - customize behavior to list all items before entering

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails-3, jquery-ui, jquery-autocomplete

I'm trying to implement autocomplete with special behaviour for a field in Rails 3.2.  I'm using the rails autocomplete gem and what I want to do is:

There is a field in a form which I want the autocomplete to work on which contains qty and the type of qty for a recipe ingredient.  Three different examples of an input:

```
100 gramms
2 pices
3.2 kilos
```

I want the behaviour to have the dropdown when the user presses space with all available options in the list.  When the user enters another key the list would of course filter on that input.

Is it possible to customize the rails autocomplete for the above behaviour?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

UPDATED. My original answer misunderstood the question.

Fisrt option.

You modify your controller action.

```
# units_controller
def autocomplete
   term = params[:term]
   quantity, unit = term.split(/\s/)
   items = unit ? Unit.where('units.name LIKE ?',"#{unit}%") : []
   json = items.collect do |item| 
     { "id" => item.id.to_s, 
       "label" => item.name, 
       "value" => "#{quantity} #{item.name} "  
     }
   end
   render json: json
end
```

While the autocomplete behaviour will already be correct, this solution is suboptimal since it hits the server even while i am typing the quantity (and gives no results).

A complete solution involves patching the rails autocompleter driver.
Keep the abaove custom controller action and just put a custom minLength function
https://github.com/crowdint/rails3-jquery-autocomplete/blob/master/lib/assets/javascripts/autocomplete-rails-uncompressed.js#L63

you modify this section as:

```
   search: function() {
     // custom minLength
     var term = extractLast( this.value );
     var filter = jQuery(this).attr('data-input-filter');
     if (filter != null) { 
        var re = new RegExp(filter,"");
        term = term.replace(re, "$1"); //ignore parts of it
     }
     if ( term.length < 1 ) { //modify to 1
       return false;
     }
   },
```

now if you put this minlength filter to your field tag

```
'data-input-filter' => j("^.*\s+([^\s]+)$")
```

it will correctly ignore the first bit (upto after the last white space) of the user input and only hits the server when you reach the first character of the unit. (little unsure of escapes here)

An advantage of this approach is that you could add ingredient autocompletion to your controller, and use comma and get multiple ingredients input simply by adding this option to autocomplete text field helper:

```
"data-delimiter" => ','
```

Then you can properly autocomplete inputs like:

```
1 kilo flour, 2 spoons sugar, 100 gramms yeast.
```

Comment: Are you saying I user input should be in the form: "10, eggs"?  I think space would be better suited and I would like the dropdown to appear right after the user precess space after the number.

Comment: oh wait, I think I totally misunderstand your post, you want single autocomplete only (i thought you want several items one after the other like in stackoverflow tagging). Instead you want only one but not firing on quantity only after space? that is possible too.

Comment: Yes, firing the quantity after the space with initially all possibilities in the list (because you haven't entered any letter) and then after entering first letter normal functionality.  Do you have any tips on how to accomplish this?

Comment: are you using rails3-jquery-autocomplete?

Comment: Yes, I'm using rails3-jquery-autocomplete.

Comment: thanks for accepting, though i didnot answer your question. I will try now :)

Comment: Thanks - I will dive into this in 2-3 days and keep you posted.

Answer (score 0):

There is also a pure js solution, so you can keep it simple in your controller

```
# units controller
autocomplete :unit, :name
```

and you need to modify rails3-jquery-autocomplete js driver.

One crucial line is this.
https://github.com/crowdint/rails3-jquery-autocomplete/blob/master/lib/assets/javascripts/autocomplete-rails-uncompressed.js#L45
you could customize here how user input relates to actual term sent to server for completion.

Problem is that you also have to make sure the value inserted on selection contains the quantity. Since this value is taken from the server json response, if you do not send the quantity to the server, you gotta remember it in a js attribute at extract

```
function extractLast( term ) {
  var last = split( term ).pop().replace(/^\s+/,"");
  var arr = last.split(/\s+/);
  if (arr.length > 1) {  
     var res = arr.pop();
     jQuery(this).attr('data-quantity').val(arr.join(' '));
  }
  return res;
}
```

and insert it on line
https://github.com/crowdint/rails3-jquery-autocomplete/blob/master/lib/assets/javascripts/autocomplete-rails-uncompressed.js#L77

```
terms.push( (jQuery(this).attr('data-quantity')) + ' ' + ui.item.value );
```

Surely nicer code would make this dependent on input field data attributes like in my accepted answer.

This solution also does not allow parsing ingredients or filtering units based on quantity, since only unit part is sent off with request.

Comment: Thanks - I will dive into this in 2-3 days and keep you guys posted.